# providing random read access to a very large (50GB+) ASCII file

Tags: c#, io, bigdata, memory-mapped-files

My task is to provide random read access to a very large (50GB+) ASCII text file (processing requests for nth line/nth word in nth line) in a form of C# console app.

After googling and reading for a few days, I've come to such vision of implementation:
Since **StreamReader** is good at sequential access, use it to build an index of lines/words in file (`List<List<long>>` map, where `map[i][j]` is position where jth word of ith line starts). And then use the index to access file through [**MemoryMappedFile**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx), since it good at providing random access.

Are there some obvious flaws in the solution? Would it be optimal for a given task?

**UPD**: It will be executed at 64bit system.

Comment: Even this list is likely to be pretty large. I would probably just have some sort of indexed structure, say a balanced tree, with every 100th line or so with its starting file offset and then seek to there and read a buffer that could then be parsed to find the exact word you were looking for.

Comment: I would do the index creation purely in terms of bytes (i.e., using `Stream` instead of `StreamReader`), but apart from that it sounds good. If there are not too many words per line, it might be more efficient to index only the lines and search for the word each time it's requested. Defer creating `String` objects as long as possible.

Answer (score 5):

It seems fine, but if you're using MemoryMapping then your program will only work on a 64-bit system because you're excessing the effective 2GB address space available.

You'll be fine with just using a `FileStream` and calling `.Seek()` to jump to the selected offset as appropriate, so I don't see a need for using MemoryMapped files.

Comment: I can see advantages in using MemoryMapped files, e.g., when related data is nearby and the page is still in physical memory. I'm not sure if you get the same advantages if you jump around in the Stream with Seek.

Comment: the 2GB limitation can be bypassed using `MemoryMappedViewAccessor`.  Its like a window into the memory.

Comment: if FilesStream.Seek() is as fast as accessing specific position through MMF (is it true?), then why we need MMF at all?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your solution is a good start - even thou List container is not the best Map container - Lists are very slow to read arbitrary elements.

I would test whether doing `List<List<long>>` map is the best in terms of memory/speed tradeoff - since OS caches memory maps at page boundaries (4096 bytes on x86/x64), it might be actually faster to only look up the address of the start of each line, and then scan the line looking for words.

Obviously, this approach would only work on 64bit OS, but the performance benefit of an MMap is significant - this is one of the few places where going 64bit matters a lot - database applications :)

Comment: "Lists are very slow to read arbitrary elements" - didn't get it, list[n] is O(1), isn't it?

Comment: also, nothing was said about lines/words ratio, the whole 50GB file may consist of a single line, a single word may be much larger than a line, so I believe I should treat lines and words as equal.